# Unable to mount ecryptfs home, after years of uninterrupted work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I have old machine with Ubuntu updated from 11.04 to 15.04, with encrypted $HOME like [described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome).

Around two-three years after installation (around about one year or two years ago) username was changed, and not sure what was passphrase set to, if it was set at all (but I assume this was required, so it is not empty).

While system was on, I could use my normal GNU/Linux login&password, and my $HOME was automatically mounted and umounted. It worked also in case of short breaks - I guess, up to several days of this machine being turned off, then back on and not requiring passphrase from me.

However, this time I left it turned off for long time and later tried to login, my `.ICEAuthority` was inaccessible, so I checked in console and I found out that ecrypt prevented automount of my $HOME (despite that I sucessfully logged in/authenticated with username&password). I am now required to provide login passphrase...

I am quite (~80%) sure that I have not prepared any suggessted by Ubuntu recovery disk. Just didn't imagine it'll ask me for this passphrase ever (again, if it was required to set it at all).

Now, since this is my machine, I can:
- su,
- access keyctl
- access 
 - /home/USERNAME/.ecryptfs symlinked to /home/.ecryptfs/OLDUSERNAME/.encryptfs

1. *Is there a way to recover/reset passphrase (access old $HOME) from wrapped-passphrase.* **NO. And I am not asking about that.**
2. **Not having enough knowledge about Kernel's keyrings, could keyctl - be used somehow to gain access?**
   `keyctl show @u` (user) is empty, while `keyctl show @us` (user default) keyring is not. Is it possible to gain some insight into the matter using kernel keyring, or is it dead end.
3. **I tried also `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` but failed (-5)**

   - either I typed wrong passphrase (which is likely, it's been years. I might have written it down somewhere...or might not),
   - *could* it have trobule unwrapping, could this be the reason, due to changed username and thus - $HOME location? (is that possible that passphrase is ok, but unwrapping fails?)
4. What are my other options **if any**, excluding searching have I saved passphrase anywhere, and dictionary/bruteforce attacks?

I'm quite aware that it might be 4th option only (I've read eCrypts  [Q. I forgot my password/lost my key! What can I do to recover my data?](http://ksouedu.com/doc/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-faq.html#lostkey)
What I mostly wonder how did that happen, and how it was actually possible for Ubuntu to mount $HOME without this passphrase in first place...for so many years? Where are settings to set this timeout?

Comment: Backup copies of the wanted data would be handy now, and copies of the (encrypted) home files in case of file/disk corruption, and a copy of the eCryptfs master key/passphrase (the one that's wrapped & kept in the wrapped-passphrase file). Encryption means backups are even more important.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have a backup, so I'm not terribly worried about this data loss. Yet as with all backups, they tend to be somewhat stale even few days after being made. Are You perhaps familar with where are eCrypt's settings? Where do You configure when should autologin cache expire?

Comment: afaik there is no auto-login for an encrypted home, it rather defeats the purpose. There is an auto-login for a separate private folder, but I think it still uses the login passphrase to unlock a wrapped-passphrase file

Comment: Well, You might be right, but in that case how come it didn't ask me for passphrase for year and half?